Create composed key (YEAR+COUNT) field with trigger after insert in SQLITE
I have a table Product with two columns: name of product and price, the unique key should be a value composed from the values combined YEAR+COUNT(10):
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YearCounters (
    year INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);

-- Product Table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    price REAL
);

On each insert, I want to generate the id based on the value of 'name' and 'YEARCOUNT_id' (NOT NULL):
INSERT INTO Products (name, price) VALUES ('Produit B', 20.15)
INSERT INTO Products (name, price) VALUES ('Produit C', 23.75);

Exemple:
SELECT * FROM Products;

2024000000000001|Produit B|20.15
2024000000000002|Produit C|23.75

So, I have write a table TRIGGER but doesn't running  .
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS increment_counter_and_set_product_id
BEFORE INSERT ON Products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- 
    UPDATE YearCounters
    SET counter = counter + 1
    WHERE year = strftime('%Y', 'now');

    --
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO YearCounters (year, counter)
    VALUES (strftime('%Y', 'now'), 0);

    --
    SELECT counter
    INTO temp_counter
    FROM YearCounters
    WHERE year = strftime('%Y', 'now');

    -- 
    SET NEW.id = strftime('%Y', 'now') || printf('%010d', temp_counter);
END;

Mistakes:

Parse error near line near "INTO": syntax error
SELECT counter     INTO temp_counter     FROM Y
error here ---^

What am I doing wrong?

You're not allowed to modify NEW values in BEFORE triggers. According to the documentation you can only execute sequence of simple statements (insert, update, delete, expr) within a trigger. You can however create an INSTEAD OF trigger upon a view that will insert calculated values into underlying table(s).

how do you go about it?

There are multiple options to choose from. See my answer under Sqlite column with repetitive values question where I demonstrate usage of INSTEAD OF trigger. Another point is that it's not necessary to use YearCounter table since you can derive the next number from Products table itself.

Perhaps consider:-
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (
    (
        CAST(strftime('%Y','now') AS INTEGER) /*<<<<< Year as INTEGER*/ * 1000000000000 /* increase significance of Year */
            + 1 /* Add 1 (the next/count) */
            /* get the current year's highest current used lower significance value (the count) or 0 if no such value*/
            + coalesce(
                (SELECT max(id) % 1000000000000 FROM products WHERE substr(id,1,4) = strftime('%Y', 'now'))
                ,0
            )
    ),
'Produit B', 20.15);

This:-

does not need a TRIGGER as the value is calculated when the insertion is undertaken
does not need the YearCounters table as the count is determined from the Products table for the current Year.

To demonstrate:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yearcounters;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YearCounters (
    year INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);

-- Product Table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    price REAL
);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (
    (
        CAST(strftime('%Y','now') AS INTEGER) /*<<<<< Year as INTEGER*/ * 1000000000000 /* increase significance of Year */
            + 1 /* Add 1 (the next/count) */
            /* get the current year's highest current used lower significance value (the count) or 0 if no such value*/
            + coalesce(
                (SELECT max(id) % 1000000000000 FROM products WHERE substr(id,1,4) = strftime('%Y', 'now'))
                ,0
            )
    ),
'Produit B', 20.15);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (
(
        CAST(strftime('%Y','now') AS INTEGER) /*<<<<< Year as INTEGER*/ * 1000000000000 /* increase significance of Year */
            + 1 /* Add 1 (the next/count) */
            /* get the current year's highest current used lower significance value (the count) or 0 if no such value*/
            + coalesce(
                (SELECT max(id) % 1000000000000 FROM products WHERE substr(id,1,4) = strftime('%Y', 'now'))
                ,0
            )
    ),
'Produit C', 23.75);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (
(
        CAST(strftime('%Y','now') AS INTEGER) /*<<<<< Year as INTEGER*/ * 1000000000000 /* increase significance of Year */
            + 1 /* Add 1 (the next/count) */
            /* get the current year's highest current used lower significance value (the count) or 0 if no such value*/
            + coalesce(
                (SELECT max(id) % 1000000000000 FROM products WHERE substr(id,1,4) = strftime('%Y', 'now'))
                ,0
            )
    ),
'Produit D', 25.11);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (
(
        CAST(strftime('%Y','now') AS INTEGER) /*<<<<< Year as INTEGER*/ * 1000000000000 /* increase significance of Year */
            + 1 /* Add 1 (the next/count) */
            /* get the current year's highest current used lower significance value (the count) or 0 if no such value*/
            + coalesce(
                (SELECT max(id) % 1000000000000 FROM products WHERE substr(id,1,4) = strftime('%Y', 'now'))
                ,0
            )
    ),
'Produit E', 26.22);
SELECT * FROM products;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yearcounters;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;

Results in the SELECT showing:-


note that the significance multiplier may need adjusting to exactly suit
the DROP's (start and end) are just for keeping a tidy demo environment
of course the embedded comments could be removed

